# "Capture by move" does not prevent capture by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

When I write `[&,x](){ /* making use of x */ }`, `x` is captured by value.

When I write `[=,&x](){ /* making use of x */ }`, `x` is captured by reference.

If I try writing `[&x, x](){ … }` I get an error telling me `x` can appear only once in a capture list.

However, `[&x, y = std::move(x)](){ /* making use of x and y */ }();` compiles fine but I get a segmentation fault.

Why does the code even compile? Why does the standard allow that I capture a variable by reference and I also use it in a "capture by-move" init capture?

Comment: *"but I get a segmentation fault."*. that is due to an incorrect body for the lambda. as it seems you wrongly use the moved-from `x`.

Comment: *"an error telling me x can appear only once in a capture list"* - It's kinda hard to put all the constraints about init-capture into a succinct error message. What's important is to bear in mind what parts of the capture are translated into members of the closure. We can't have two different members with the same name. That's the context for "must appear once".

Comment: @Jarod42, that's my point. And I can (erroneously) make use of `x` in the body because I'm _also_ capturing it by reference, beside moving it into `y`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I think your comment could be very well an answer.

Comment: rust disallows to use moved from object, C++ allows it and you might even have valid cases. Notice also that `auto y = std::move(x); auto lambda = [&x, &y](){/*..*/};` would have similar behavior as your.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case `[&x, y = std::move(x)](){ };` is quite legal from the point of view of the compiler, because different identifiers are used for capture. The standard says the following:

[[expr.prim.lambda/capture-2]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-2)

> Ignoring appearances in *initializers* of *init-captures*, an identifier or *this* shall not appear more than once in a *lambda-capture*.

```
[&i, a = i]{ };    // OK
[&i, a = std::move(i)]{ };    // OK

[&i, i]{ };       // error: i repeat
[&i, i = std::move(i)]{ };    // error: i repeated
```